# Anistropic shader: mine doesn't converge at centre

Tags: shaders

When I used Anistropic shader, my highlights do not converge at the centre as opposed to Blender Guru's example. Why is that so? Thank you.
[link to tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4MTnpnahu0)

[image: my saucepan][image: my node tree]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your cylinder has been rotated in *Edit Mode* and its vertical axis isn't the *Z* axis anymore.

Fixing it is not straightforward. You should either rotate it back (still in *Edit Mode*) if you can tell which one would be the right rotation, or you should use custom transform orientations -- which are a bit of an overkill.

If the geometry isn't too complicated, I'd suggest starting this object over.